# CSS select :nth-of-class() alternative

Tags: css, css-selectors

With CSS: how do I target the first class of "approach", the second and the third one. All individually because they need different styles. I can't add an extra class to avoid responsive disorientation.

HTML code:

```
<div class="approaches">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <a href="#" class="approach">content here...</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <a href="#" class="approach">content here...</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <a href="#" class="approach">content here...</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS code (which doesn't work at the moment):

```
.approaches .approach:nth-of-type(1){
    color: red;
}
.approaches .approach:nth-of-type(2){
    color: green;
}
.approaches .approach:nth-of-type(3){
    color: blue;
}
```

Comment: Can you move class="approach" up a level to div's?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a `<div>` between the `.approaches` and the `.approach` elements preventing your `:nth` selector from working properly. The selector looks for elements in their own nesting level, and because the `.approach` elements are wrapped in `<div>`s, they have separate nesting levels. Use the selector on the `<div>`s instead:

```
.approaches div:nth-of-type(1) .approach {
    color: red;
}
.approaches div:nth-of-type(2) .approach {
    color: green;
}
.approaches div:nth-of-type(3) .approach {
    color: blue;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer. Never used this type of selectors before and didn't knew about the nesting issue.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `.approaches div:nth-of-type(1) .approach { }`, as others have suggested, but this assumes that each and every div inside `.approaches` has an `a` with the the `.approach` class, so it cannot really be considered to be a general way to achieve the equivalent of the non-existent `nth-of-class` if that's what you want.

To do that, you could use a bit of JS:

```
[].forEach.call(document.getElementsByClassName('approach'), function(elt, i) {
    elt.classList.add('approach-' + i);
});

.approach-1 { color: red; }
```

Generalizing this for any class:

```
function add_nth_of_class(cls) {
    [].forEach.call(document.getElementsByClassName(cls), function(elt, i) {
        elt.classList.add(cls + '-' + i);
});

add_nth_of_class('approach');
```

However, this will number the classes sequentially throughout the document. To get a true `nth-of-class`, based on the position within the parent element, we would need to do something like the following, using the little-known TreeWalker API:

```
function add_nth_of_class(cls) {
    var walker = document.createTreeWalker(document, NodeFlter.SHOW_ELEMENT), n;

    while (n = walker.nextNode()) {                    //for each node in turn,
        [].filter.call(n.childNodes, function(elt) {   //find the children which 
            return elt.classList.contains(cls);        //contain the class we want
        }).forEach(function(elt, i) {                  //and for each of those
            elt.classList.add(cls + '-' + (i+1));      //add a numbered class
        });
    }   
}
```

CSS:

```
.approach-1 { // targets all elements with class .approach first within their parent
```

Answer (score -1):

```
.approaches > div:nth-child(1) .approach {

}

.approaches > div:nth-child(2) .approach {

}

.approaches > div:nth-child(3) .approach {

}
```